# How to fix Component-Streching when using vh with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to layout a website using flexbox layout. The main goal is to have a header, a footer and a navigation to the left. The main and aside parts are to be placed in the middle and to the right. So far i got it to work using the following:

```css
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html * {
    /* debugging */
    border: 1px dotted hotpink;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
   /* height: 100vh; */
}

nav {
    width: 10%;
}

main {
    width: 75%;
}

aside {
    width: 15%;
}

header, footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: hotpink;
}

main {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

nav {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: royalblue;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>THIS IS THE REALLY BIG HEADER</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga unde consequatur laborum cupiditate odio ipsa
        cumque, dolorem temporibus aut ipsam commodi autem maiores delectus non vitae recusandae magni consequuntur ab!
    </main>
    <aside>aside</aside>
    <footer>(c) by me</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

However: When using the line
       /* height: 100vh; */
all components are stretched to use the whole screen-height. My intent is to just make the navigation, main and aside stretch, but let the header and footer use only the space they need. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

1) Set for `<body>` tag property

```
flex-flow: column;
min-height: 100vh;
```

2) Add wrapper for tags `<nav>`, `<main>`, `<aside>`and set for this properties

```
flex-grow: 1;
display: flex;
```

### Result

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html * {
  /* debugging */
  border: 1px dotted hotpink;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  width: 10%;
}

main {
  width: 75%;
}

aside {
  width: 15%;
}

header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

nav {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.page {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>THIS IS THE REALLY BIG HEADER</h1>
</header>
<div class="page">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga unde consequatur laborum cupiditate odio ipsa cumque, dolorem temporibus aut ipsam commodi autem maiores delectus non vitae recusandae magni consequuntur ab!
  </main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</div>
<footer>(c) by me</footer>
```

And same code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/BaBMObv)

[image]

Comment: Let me try to understand your idea: You wrap the "middle" part in another flex-container and make it grow depending on the size of the page, whereas the header and footer elements are placed inside a container that dows not resize. Did i get that right?

Comment: I did not use you exact code, but this pointed me in the right direction. Using 2 flex containers totally worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
body { 
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: This makes the header and footer use only as much space as needed, but now the footer is not aligned to the bottom of the page anymore and the "middle" part does not stretch eighter.

Comment: Well then read the flexbox documentation :) you can use align-self on items or just margin-bottom:0px on footer etc... go and try .